# Tweet when comment is created with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter, tweets

I'm using the wp-twitter plugin (with WordPress 3.0.1) to automaticaly create tweets when a post is created and it's working great!

Now I needed to create tweets when a comment is created...do you know any plugin that does that?

Or even, if you had changed the wp-twitter plugin to do that, give me some guidelines please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`comment_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) hook and add action that will submit the content to your twitter account.

Example:

```
function tweet_comment($comment_ID, $approved) {
   if($approved) {
      $comment = get_comment($comment_ID);
      //Submit to twitter => $comment->comment_content
      $consumerKey = '<insert your consumer key';
      $consumerSecret = '<insert your consumer secret>';
      $oAuthToken = '<insert your access token>';
      $oAuthSecret = '<insert your token secret>';

      require_once('<insert_path_to_twitteroauth>/twitteroauth.php');

      // create a new instance
      $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $oAuthToken, $oAuthSecret);

      //send a tweet
      $tweet->post('statuses/update', array('status' => substr($comment->comment_content, 0, 140)));
   }
}
add_action('comment_post','tweet_comment', 10, 2);
```